# Preventing access to apache sites via server ip in browser

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to set up an apache webserver to serve multiple websites, and I'd like to be able to block access via the ip address of the server itself.

i.e. if someone was to put in `http://84.320.65.4/site-name` for example, the site in question would be served. However I only want them to be able to access the site via the domain specified in the sites-enabled configuration.

Where and how do I go about configuring this, or is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Look at the example: "Running several name-based web sites on a single IP address"

This should prevent you from using the IP to access the site.  Should you do this? Up to you.  The downside is that the DNS has to be configured properly and it will be trickier to do internal testing, but that's not a stopper by any means. So long as the site's code is done with relational hyperlinks you won't run into many issues either way.

Comment: That is similar to how I have set my webserver up, but i can still access my site via `ip address/site-name`

Comment: Can you post this area of your configuration to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look over Apache Virtual Hosts [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/), especially the [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) directive.

Here is a *sample configuration* for your need:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 84.320.65.4

    DocumentRoot /var/www/website/

    <Directory /var/www/website/>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit**: with the above configuration, the `/var/www/` directory won't be browsable.

Your websites will be accessible by the URLs `http://84.320.65.4/foo` or `http://84.320.65.4/bar` (respectively corresponding to `/var/www/website/foo` and `/var/www/website/bar`).

You could put a basic HTML page in `/var/www/website/` to warn the user directly accessing to `http://84.320.65.4`

Comment: This is less a question on how to set up multiple websites on one IP, and more how do you block access to the root /var/www directory & it's contents via inputting into a browser the IP address of the server itself.

Comment: @Dan Brooks: In IIS we call it using host headers.  If you have multiple sites using the same IP and port you can tell the server to route requests based on the host name they're looking for.  If your server is set up like that it won't reply when you look for that host's IP address because it's shared by several hosts. I'm not sure if there's another way to do it, but it's an easy way to trick it into doing the functionality you're looking for.